# Excel Macro to perform multi column sort

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro in Excel that will sort spreadsheets by columns A, C and F. I found information online to get me started. Below is the code. The challenge I'm having is, the spreadsheet will contain a different number of rows each day. (The columns will always be the same but the row count will change). The below script will sort my data as long as the spreadsheet does not contain more than 9999 rows (that includes column headings). If I have 10,000 or more rows, the macro fails.

How do I update the below code to allow it to run regardless of the number of rows? Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thank you

```
Sub Multi_Sort()
'
' Multi_Sort Macro
'
Dim lngLast As Long
lngLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A1" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C1" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F1:F1" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange Range("A1:F" & lngLast)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the macro fails" ?

Comment: I get a Run-time error '1004':

Comment: Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate your error in Excel 2013, but I'm guessing the extra "1" in your range assignments is the problem (i.e., change `=Range("A1:A1" & lngLast)` to `=Range("A1:A" & lngLast)`, etc.).

Also, a good practice would be to be explicit in your range calls (include the worksheet).

```
Sub Multi_Sort()

Dim lngLast As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lngLast = ws.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With .Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A1:A" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("C1:C" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("F1:F" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:F" & lngLast)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good spot. I suspect if the macro is running on Excel 2003 or in compatibility mode, when `lngLast` is greater than 10,000 then the resulting range would be `A1:A110000 (A1:A1 + 10000)` - something older Excel can not handle.